# What is the best method of re-rendering a web page on orientation change?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, orientation

I have a fluid CSS layout which is rendering badly on an iphone when I change the orientation. (It looks fine when it is refreshed).

I am using the code below to refresh the page on orientation change, which works fine - it just feels a little wrong doing so. Is there any way of achieving this without having to reload the entire page? It is a mobile site, I don't really want to force the user to load the page twice.

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    window.location.reload()
}, false);
```

Edit:

The two main issues when testing on an iphone are:

I have a  which is 100% width, with a right aligned background image. 
When I change the orientation from portrait to landscape the body width remains as how it rendered on portrait mode and vice versa. It is more of an issue from landscape to portrait as the page is too wide and it seems to render the images twice.

Comment: Are you using CSS media queries already?

Comment: @Pointy nope, no media queries. The page layout is the same wether it is horizontal or vertical (the same CSS). I have updated my answer to explain a bit better.

Comment: Are you making your page for iphone only? What about ipad, android, WM7 etc.? If having a different width/size browser causes your page to display poorly you need to look at the layout.

Comment: @Ryan Ternier yes, all mobiles. The layout displays fine if the page is refreshed after the orientation has changed, so it isn't a layout issue, the issue lies when the phone renders the page after an orientation transition.

Comment: @theorise got an example page so i can test what you described?

Comment: CSS media queries support orientation: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

Comment: Your above script changes refreshes the page on every window re-size even on desktop so small revision...

var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window;
        
        if (supportsOrientationChange) {
            window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
                window.location.reload()
            }, false);
        }

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming your CSS is already happily rendering on your various size mobile device screens, you need to define the viewport in the <head> of your template.

Example, this sets the page width to be the device's screen width and an initial zoom of 100%. Initial zoom is applied at page load, but not when the orientation is changed.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

By adding a maximum-scale=1.0 parameter to the viewport you will force the iPad/iPhone to maintain the zoom level and re-layout the page on orientation change. The disadvantage of this is that it will disable zooming. However, the advantage is that you can make layout adjustments with media queries to present the content in a suitable fashion for the current orientation. You can read more about viewport here: [Choosing a ViewPort](http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/)

Now onto media queries. You should put media queries at the bottom of your CSS file and in the order of smallest width to largest width for screen widths. For example, taken from the [Html5BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) CSS example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports 480px and over go here */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports 768px and over go here */

}
```

So all your normal styles are above this and applied first, then if the screen is 480px or wider the next block of styles are applied, then if the screen is 768px or wider the last block of styles are applied.

By combining the fixed zoom level to 1.0 and the media-queries, you can make your site responsively resize to the screen size and orientation without javascript. Obviously you need to make sure the site is then well designed so users don't need zooming. If your site is optimized for mobile this shouldn't be a problem.

Please note: other non-safari mobile browsers may re-layout the page without setting the maximum-scale on the viewport. But this behavior is inconsistent and most developers seem to cater to apple devices even if the implementation is worse than other devices. Some other devices would maintain the zoom level and recenter the viewport when the orientation changes. But all devices are ok to fix the zoom level to 1.0.

Comment: It looks like you could forgoe the maximum-scale suggested above and augment the layout with some javascript if you like (without reloading the page). Check out this other stackoverflow page on manipulating the viewport via JavaScript: [Manipulate ViewPort with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon)

Comment: There are also `orientation:landscape` and `orientation:portrait` media queries you can use.

Comment: @BobAman You are correct, I think the reason the Html5Boilerblate CSS uses the screen widths is for cross platform support including desktops/laptops. For example what if you just resized your browser window on your desktop machine to a portrait looking shape. (ex: Press Win+Left on a windows 7 machine to take up half your screen on the left side - commonly used for viewing 2 apps side by side). But I suppose you could expand the above media queries to include dimensional adjustments AND orientation adjustments if you needed those scenarios to be different.

Comment: It's also an issue of device dimension support being more wide-spread.

Comment: BenSwayne's answer: "By adding a maximum-scale=1.0 parameter to the viewport you will force the iPad/iPhone to maintain the zoom level and re-layout the page on orientation change." does not seem to work anymore. Pages do not re-layout. Has an iOS update since this thread was answered changed something?

Comment: As of Safari 7, this no longer works. Here's a [demo](https://idorecall.com/static/bug-demos/iPad-rotation-SO-8004405-1269037/). To make sure you see how it doesn't work, start with the iPad in landscape mode, load the page, then rotate. Notice the page doesn't expand to full height, despite using flexbox all the way.

Answer (score 14):

## 2015 update

All the other answers are incorrect or outdated. Here's what works:

```js
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
    var originalBodyStyle = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('display');
    document.body.style.display='none';
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.body.style.display = originalBodyStyle;
    }, 10);
  });
```

The code listens to the [orientationchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange) and forces a re-flow of the `body` element by hiding it and showing it 10 milliseconds later. It does not depend on any `<meta>` tags or media queries.

Other answers suggested using media queries, but you already use them, since you said "It looks fine when it is refreshed".

Some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196263/1269037) answers suggest using `location.reload()`. This is very inefficient, because it will reload the entire page, including images etc. Especially on mobile, you don't want to do that.

Yet other answers suggested adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` or variations thereof. As of Safari 7, this no longer works. Here's a [demo](https://idorecall.com/static/bug-demos/iPad-rotation-SO-8004405-1269037/). To make sure you see how it doesn't work, start with the iPad in landscape mode, load the page, then rotate. Notice the page doesn't expand to full height, despite using flexbox all the way.

Compare that to [this page](https://iDoRecall.com?ref=SO-7919172), where we use the hide/show body technique in production.

Comment: This works for me right out of the box. Great solution.

Comment: OK so I said thank you prematurely. It is NOT working for me, and I do have the meta tag set properly.  The div in question is a dynamically-rendered slideshow which creates a child div with inline style positioning absolute.  It's some third party thing so of course I can't touch the code itself directly (and I don't have the option of telling my employer to junk it) so ... throw me a bone, anyone!

Comment: what if the orientationchange event got triggered twice within 10 miliseconds .. there are chances that you'll completely loose body display property & endup with display none ...
@Dan Dascalescu

Answer (score 3):

Used a method that causes a repaint and a reflow in a single javascript stack frame. Not keen on viewport specific answers as it is often a requirement for accessibility to keep pinch zooming etc.

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
    document.body.style.display='none';
    document.body.offsetHeight; //cause a reflow
    document.body.style.display='block'; //cause a repaint
});
```

Or non-jquery equivalent

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
    document.body.style.display='none';
    document.body.offsetHeight; //cause a reflow
    document.body.style.display='block'; //cause a repaint
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience  the best way is to  have it like this

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width /">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

Doing it like @BenSwayne  in my experience does not rescale back to the initial scale when you change the orientation. Dont know why that is

Comment: That doesn't work either. Here's a [demo](https://idorecall.com/static/bug-demos/iPad-rotation-SO-21602276-1269037/). To make sure you see how it doesn't work, start with the iPad in landscape mode, load the page, then rotate. Notice the page doesn't expand to full height, despite using flexbox all the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this is how I fixed it with jQuery.

In my case the styles were not changing correctly for my `<nav>` element. I used a modified version of kidkaos77's code combined with `$.get()` to only load a certain part of the page:

```
$(window).bind("resize",function() {
    //on resize reload only nav & replace
    $.get("index.php" +  ' nav', function(data) {
        $("nav").replaceWith($(data).find("nav"));
    });
});
```

With this method you don't have to reload the entire page, but you would have to specify exactly which elements are being affected by the orientation change, which in your case it seems like you just need one div.

Comment: Can this solution be used without the page name? Just $.get(this + ' div.className', function(data) ... ?  If not, why not?

Answer (score -1):

Another option could be to add & remove CSS classes from your html elements (div, var, span, etc).
This way you can modify only the elements that are giving you troubles and also you can adjust the content on non-mobile browsers if the user resize the browser window.

Here is the Javascript/JQuery code you will need:

```
// Code to run when page has finished loading
$(function() {
    // Add CSS-class to body depending on device platform using user agent string
    // You can add more validations here and/or separate Android from iPhone or add more customized classes like "landscape_iPad", "landscape_iPhone", etc.
   // You can also validate browser types and add classes like "background_IE" or "background_Chrome", etc
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") != -1)) {
        $("#background").addClass("landscape");
    } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) || 
    (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1)) {
        $("body").addClass("iPhone");
    }

    // Get the initial orientation on iOS devices
    if (!isNaN(window.orientation)) {
        var orientation = ($(window).width() < 980) ? "portrait" : "landscape";
        // Index php
        $("#background").addClass(orientation);
    } else {
        // Choose layout depending on viewport/window width
        var orientation = ($(window).width() < 980) ? "portrait" : "landscape";
        // Index php
        $("#background").addClass(orientation);
    }

    // Bind orientationChange (or viewport/window size changes)
    if (window.onorientationchange != undefined) {
        window.onorientationchange = function() {
            var orientation = ($(window).width() < 980) ? "portrait" : "landscape";
            // Index php
            $("#background").removeClass("portrait landscape").addClass(orientation);
        }
    } else {
        // Use landscape styling if it's wider than 980 pixels. 
        // This is for non mobile browsers, this way if the user resize the browser window, content will adjust too.
        $(window).bind('resize', function(){
            var orientation = ($(window).width() < 980) ? "portrait" : "landscape";
            // Index php
            $("#background").removeClass("portrait landscape").addClass(orientation);
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the CSS class for the sample element "background":

```
#background.portrait {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:768px;
    height:946px;
    z-index:0;
    background:url(background.png) top center no-repeat;
}
#background.landscape {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;
    width:1024px;
    height:724px;
    z-index:0;
    background:url(background_landscape.png) top center no-repeat;
}
```

This way you can customize the landscape and portrait behavior and you can add more clases like: "landscape_iPhone", "portrait_Android" or whatever you need to control the rendering of the page for each specific device.

Also, you don't need to reload the page, it will adjust it on the fly.

Hope it helps you or someone else =), this has enabled me to create web sites customized for each screen size, mobile brand or even browser type with the same HTML but different CSS classes.

Comment: I applaud your fervor, but UserAgent sniffing is becoming "passe" in favor of feature detection. You never know when the next tablet or browser will hit the market that might break your UserAgent sniffing. Also I don't see what this accomplishes that media queries do not. We aren't trying to support IE6 for orientation changes, so we can confidently use the appropriate current technology. IMO, JavaScript should only be used to fill in the shortfalls between browsers, namely the difference between iOS' Safari's viewport handling and other tablet browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$(function(){

    changeOrientation(window.orientation == 0 ? "portrait" : "landscape");

    $('body').bind('orientationchange',function(event){
        changeOrientation(event.orientation)
    });

    function changeOrientation(ori){
        $("#orientation").removeClass('portrait landscape');
        $("#orientation").addClass(ori);
    }     
});
```

Comment: Without explanation or the HTML & CSS for the `#orientation` element, I suspect the intent is identical to the hide/show of the body in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919172/what-is-the-best-method-of-re-rendering-a-web-page-on-orientation-change/31357325#31357325).

Answer (score -2):

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() { location.reload(); });
```

This code worked for me.