# refresh web-page on iPad orientation change

Tags: javascript, ios, orientation

I'd like to auto refresh/reload webpage when user tilts his iPad. I've done alot of reseach but am not able to find a solution. Before wasting another day searching for answers, does anyone know if this is this even possible?

Comment: use window.onorientationchange function to get this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
window.onorientationchange = function()
{
   window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, not working though..

Comment: Tested on iPad 2 running iOS 6 and it works verbatim.

Comment: @ThomasBLund Actually, remember the semi-colon at the end of the last closing brace.

Comment: This is unnecessarily slow, because it will reload the entire page, including images and everything. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919172/what-is-the-best-method-of-re-rendering-a-web-page-on-orientation-change/31357325#31357325) for a much faster solution (10 miliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Note: this question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919172/what-is-the-best-method-of-re-rendering-a-web-page-on-orientation-change/31357325#31357325) and should be closed. I'll post the gist of my answer here.

```js
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
    var originalBodyStyle = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('display');
    document.body.style.display='none';
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.body.style.display = originalBodyStyle;
    }, 10);
  });
```

The code listens to the [orientationchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange) and forced a re-flow of the `body` element by hiding it and showing it 10 milliseconds later. It does not depend on any `<meta>` tags or media queries. And it doesn't reload the entire page.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the delegate of UIWebview on orientation change like this

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
     [_webview reload];
}
```

You also need to include UIWebviewDelegate in .h file and assign delegate to self.

Comment: This is not JavaScript. OP was looking for a JS solution.